# HTML5 Canvas dropshadow not obeying restore() function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently trying to create a multi level glow effect with a few different drop shadows on a few filled paths.

However when trying to restore the context, it doesnt obey the restore function and applies the last dropshadow shadowColor and shadowBlur to all dropshadows.

Here is the current canvas context:

```
            var c=document.getElementById("paradigm");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(31,21);
            ctx.lineTo(142,21);
            ctx.lineTo(151,38);
            ctx.lineTo(141,44);
            ctx.lineTo(32,44);
            ctx.lineTo(22,38);
            ctx.closePath();                
            ctx.fillStyle="#111111";
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(95,235,255,0.09)';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(153,42);
            ctx.lineTo(163,60);
            ctx.lineTo(109,155);
            ctx.lineTo(89,155);
            ctx.lineTo(89,143);
            ctx.lineTo(141,49);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="#111111";
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(95,235,255,0.09)';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(20,42);
            ctx.lineTo(32,49);
            ctx.lineTo(85,143);
            ctx.lineTo(85,155);
            ctx.lineTo(65,155);
            ctx.lineTo(10,60);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="#111111";
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(95,235,255,0.09)';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();

            ctx.shadowColor='rgba(228,105,22,0.5)';
            ctx.shadowBlur=10;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(81,68);
            ctx.lineTo(93,68);
            ctx.lineTo(99,78);
            ctx.lineTo(93,88);
            ctx.lineTo(81,88);
            ctx.lineTo(75,78);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="#cf672a";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();

            ctx.shadowColor='rgba(255,255,79,0.5)';
            ctx.shadowBlur=3;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(83,71);
            ctx.lineTo(92,71);
            ctx.lineTo(96,78);
            ctx.lineTo(91,85);
            ctx.lineTo(82,85);
            ctx.lineTo(78,78);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="#ffff4f";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(81,68);
            ctx.lineTo(93,68);
            ctx.lineTo(99,78);
            ctx.lineTo(93,88);
            ctx.lineTo(81,88);
            ctx.lineTo(75,78);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.stroke();
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/jbhX5/

What should be an orange 'glow' around the middle hexagon at 10 blur is currently a yellow 'glow' at 3 blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `save()` once but `restore()` five times.

Storing states work in the same way as a stack, where `save()` does a *push* and `restore()` does a *pop*. This means you need to match the number of calls of `restore()` with `save()`.

```
ctx.save();     // push
...
ctx.restore();  // pop

// here state will be as before save()

ctx.save();     // push
...
ctx.restore();  // pop

// here state will be as before save()
```

or

```
ctx.save();     // push
ctx.save();     // push
...
ctx.restore();  // pops second save
// here state will be as before second save()
...
ctx.restore();  // pops first save
// here state will be as before first save()
```

If you call restore without having a saved states to match the **[specs says](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-restore)** (my emphasis):

> The restore() method must pop the top entry in the drawing state
>   stack, and reset the drawing state it describes. **If there is no saved
>   state, the method must do nothing**.

In other words: the second time you call `restore()` nothing happens/nothing is restored as there existed only one state on the stack.

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbhX5/1/)**

Comment: Makes all the sense in the world. Thank you very much!